# jQuery form error checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm doing a simple jQuery form checker for a website. I have two forms on the website: a login form and a signup form. My code is as followed:

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // DOES SOME ERROR CHECKING HERE
    if { hasError $('div.error').fadeIn() }

    else { $(this).parents('form').submit() }
});
```

So my question is, both the login button and the signup button has a class called btn, how can I have the them check and submit their own form instead of checking all the forms on the page since $(this).parents('form') will get both the signup and login form?

Thank you!

Comment: Dont you like/want to use [.submit()] (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of jQuery?

Comment: @HardikPatel: He does use it, doesn't he? Or do you think of the handler registration?

Comment: @Bergi - I just wanted to make sure he wants to use it or he want to do it using click on button only... :)

Comment: Yes, I want to submit the form. The thing is $(this).parents('form').submit() will try to validate and submit all the forms on the page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/samzhao/c9GXZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML form structure so that when when you click either button, you are able to select the corresponding form.

```
<form action="get">
    <input type="text" value="1" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" />
</form>

<form action="get">
    <input type="text" value="1" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" />
</form>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

EDIT

A better selector for your error handling

```
$(this).closest('form').find('.required').each(function(){
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9GXZ/6/

Comment: Thanks. That's basically how my html looks like. The only difference is that my buttons are instead of paragraph tags. And I tried using the closest method, but it doesn't work somehow..

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant info in the jsfiddle and provided my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/XCK2q/

Comment: i get wat your saying, and i tried that as well. but it's still the same thing in my case

Comment: I didn't see your error handling, it had a similar problem.  See edits http://jsfiddle.net/c9GXZ/6/

Answer (score 2):

no $(this) will get that form whose respective btn u have clicked. "this" keyword pass object of an ellement so don't worry this code will run fine.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's not how it turns out. parents('form') will simply get all the forms containing the .btn element

Comment: try .parent() instead of parents()

Comment: nope, doesnt work. Anyways, here's a link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/samzhao/c9GXZ/

Answer (score 2):

There is something really wrong with your html markup if `$(this).parents('form')` returns more than one element. Also, consider to shorten your code to just

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {

    // DO SOME ERROR CHECKING HERE

    if (hasError) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.error').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup he is rite may be in future u have more complex code so $(this).parents('form') can be a problem.

Comment: @user14412: as the action is not prevented, the form will be submitted, won't it?

Comment: sorry, im not sure what you are suggesting.. anyways, here's the code:http://jsfiddle.net/samzhao/c9GXZ/

Comment: maybe it gets clearer if you'd use a real variable 'hasError' instead of checking for the number of div's with class="error" although you have just created all of them...

Answer (score 1):

give them id, and take it like this.

```
$('#btn1).click(....
$('#btn2).click(....
```

Comment: This one is better idea if u want to simplyfy your code for better understanding

Comment: Ya, I thought about that, but I don't want to re-write all my validation code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ahead with your code then you can go just take look on [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method of jQuery.

The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Try, to use `$(this).closest('form').submit()` instead of `$(this).parents('form').submit()`. I am not user but I think you have included form inside a form(check or share your HTML as well.)

Comment: my html is too long.. but basically, it's just two separate forms, not a form inside a another form, and the closest('form') seem to be the solution, but i somehow cant get it working..it's just gonna get both forms

Comment: @user14412 - Its quite strange, how do you come to know that its submitting both forms?

Comment: because i have the validation code in place, when i hit one of the buttons, all of the forms are checked...oh wait...maybe it's the problem of my validation code..

Comment: I don't think my validation code has any problem. I used $(this).parent() to append error displaying divs

Comment: ok...it might be my validation code...i'm completely confused now. Here's a link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/samzhao/c9GXZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // DOES SOME ERROR CHECKING HERE
    if (hasError) {  $('div.error').fadeIn(); } //some syntax change
    else { $(this).closest('form').submit() }  ///will get the nearest form element and stop there and will submit it as per your code...
});
```

**UPDATE**

replace this

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
```

with this

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(e){
```

This got it working in your jsfiddle url...

Comment: I thought this would work! But somehow it doesnt...:( I have no idea why, but it's still trying to submit both forms

Comment: could you give me something live for this??? or may be a jsfiddle url? I could check...

Comment: no i dint save it.... u just replace this $('.btn').click(function(e) { ...... with this $('.btn').on('click',function(e){    in the jsfiddle it will work

Comment: that's essentially the same thing though. on('click') and click() are the same thing according to jquery's source code

Comment: did you actually changed anything? weird i dont see any changes...driving me crazy...anyways, i got it working finally!!! thank you!